# One or more UDP networks realtime system

Tags: multithreading, sockets, udp, real-time, broadcast

I'm developing a real-time system for elevators, and I'm in need for some advice on the implementation of the network module. The network module is based on `UDP` broadcasting, and there are several things it needs to do:

- Spam a heartbeat, to know which elevators are alive
- Broadcast new order/job
- Broadcast if the elevator is doing the order/job

Now so far I've implemented only one `UDP` server, making the load of each message quite large. It contains a `JSONobject` with the following attributes:

```
STATUS
newOrders
takenOrders
orderQueue
```

My question is, should I spawn multiple threads running UDP on different ports for each elevator? If so, I could use a combination of one to send heartbeats, one to deal out orders, and one to broadcast the orderqueue. What are the pros and cons of running multiple UDP's on each client?

Comment: There is no such thing as 'multiple UDP'. Do you mean multiple sockets? It's hard to believe you will have any multi-port or  multithreading requirements in something whose peripherals are as slow as elevators.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough because of lack of knowledge in the field. I should clarify with sending different information on different ports thus on different threads. You are correct about elevators being slow, however it's part of the requirement.

Comment: This is a bit of a broad question.  Without a requirements spec and plenty of time, it's imp.. very difficult to suggest an overall system design which is, effectively, what you are asking for.   I cannot see, off-hand, why you would need any more than two threads - one to dequeue datagrams and send them, one to receive datagrams and queue them to some state-machine. The send thread could implement a timeout on its input queue and issue a heartbeat on the timeout.  I can't see why the messages are so big, or should be such a huge load, (apart from using UDP broadcast for everything).

Comment: I guess you're right. As a matter of fact, you provided me with some input that's valuable to me, so I'll consider this too-broad question finished and continuing with those two threads only.